# urdf_parser check_urdf in groovy

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't find any urdf_parser binaries at the Groovy release. Is it hidden somewhere of it didn't compile for this release?

Edit 1:
Is there a tool like urdf_parser on groovy?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51657/urdf_parser-check_urdf-in-groovy/) by [nunojpg](https://answers.ros.org/users/3842/nunojpg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This package is deprecated. You are supposed to use the urdf-dom dependency directly instead of this package.
As far as I know this is the source code the binaries are compiled from
https://github.com/ros-gbp/robot_model-release/tree/release/urdf_parser
So I guess there are no binaries in groovy.

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1